# RYacas: Increase MaxEvalDepth to solve equation

Tags: r, algebra, yacas

I am trying to solve several equations for A like the one below but continue to get the error "CommandLine(1): Max evaluation stack depth reached.
Please use MaxEvalDepth to increase the stack size as needed."

I can't seem to find information about how to increase MaxEvalDepth outside of the Yacas program. I would greatly appreciate some help!

```
library(Ryacas)

yac_str("Solve((((SI - 4.5) * (1 - exp(-1 * exp (b0 + (b1 * ln(SI - 4.5)) + (b2 * ln(A))))) / (1 - exp(-1 * exp (b0 + (b1 * ln(SI - 4.5)) + (b2 * ln(50)))))) + 4.5) * 1.05 ==H, A)")

Error in yac_core(x) : 
  Yacas returned this error: CommandLine(1) : Max evaluation stack depth reached.
Please use MaxEvalDepth to increase the stack size as needed.
```